# Filter list of dictionaries using comprehension if key can be None?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to filter list of dictionaries using list comprehension.

Since there is possibility that `arg1` or `arg2` will be `None`, is there a better way of writing this code so I don't have to check first if variable `is None` before performing list comprehension?

```
a = list of dictionaries

if arg1 is None and arg2 is None:
    result = a
elif arg1 is not None and arg2 is not None:
    result = [d for d in a if d['key1'] == arg1 and d['key2'] == arg2]
elif arg1 is not None and arg2 is None:
    result = [d for d in a if d['key1'] == arg1]
elif arg1 is None and arg2 is not None:
    result = [d for d in a if d['key2'] == arg2]
```

Comment: could you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? An example of you list of dictionaries and what are `arg1` and `arg2` (how do you pick their value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check for `is None` as part of the comprehension.  This should cover all four cases above:

```
result = [d for d in a if (arg1 is None or arg1 == d['key1']) and (arg2 is None or arg2 == d['key2'])]
```

Comment: This answer was exactly what I was looking for, it was so logical and i was so close but i got lost since i was hopeless and looking for a completely different approach. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could just try filter(), which will return an empty value if nothing is found:

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: x['key1'] == arg1, a))
result += list(filter(lambda x: x['key2'] == arg2, a))
```

Comment: In my testing, this works when *either* `arg1` or `arg2` are are passed as `not None` but seems to fail when *both* `arg1` and `arg2` are passed as `None` (should return everything, but returns nothing) or as `not None` (should return intersection, but returns union.)

Comment: Ah, gotcha.  Thanks for checking it out!

Answer (score 0):

You could filter `a` in two separate steps:

```
result = a.copy()

if arg1 is not None:
    result = [d for d in result if d['key1'] == arg1]

if arg2 is not None:
    result = [d for d in result if d['key2'] == arg2]
```

Though this might be slower for large lengths of `a`.